# Case without select case error drop down code

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

I keep on getting the **Case without select case** error while trying to apply code to make all drop downs to the right of a cell reset/change back to choose when an option on the left has changed.

I am very new to VBA and the macro side of excel and like I said above, I am trying to get this code to apply to the whole worksheet, i want to make it so when selecting drop down options, is if go back and change one element the future elements (everything to the right) changes back to the "Choose" option.

I found some code online and have tried to change it to suit my needs however whenever i try to run it i get the case without case error.
Example of the code i am using is below:

```
Option Explicit

Const CHOOSE = "Choose"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim nextCell As Range
    Dim oldCalc As Excel.XlCalculation

    If Not Intersect(Target, [DataEntryTable]) Is Nothing Then
        If [Radio_Choice] = 1 Then
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                oldCalc = .Calculation
                .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            End With

            For Each targetCell In Target
                'Clear any cells that use 'SubList' to the right of targetCell in the current table.
                If targetCell.Column < (targetCell.ListObject.ListColumns.Count + targetCell.ListObject.Range.Column - 1) Then 'there are table cells to the right
                    For Each nextCell In targetCell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, targetCell.ListObject.ListColumns.Count + targetCell.ListObject.Range.Column - targetCell.Column - 1)
                        If HasValidationFormula(nextCell) Then
                            If nextCell.Validation.Formula1 = "=SubList" Then nextCell.Value = ""
                        End If
                    Next nextCell
                End If
                 Select Case Target.Cells.Validation.Formula1                    
                    Case "=SubList"
                        If targetCell.Value = "" Then
                            targetCell.Value = CHOOSE
                        ElseIf targetCell.Offset(, -1).Value = CHOOSE Then
                            targetCell.Value = ""
                        ElseIf targetCell.Value = CHOOSE Then
                            'Do nothing
                        Else
                            Set nextCell = targetCell.Offset(, 1)
                            If HasValidationFormula(nextCell) Then
                                If nextCell.Validation.Formula1 = "=SubList" Then nextCell.Value = CHOOSE
                            End If
                        End If
                    End Select
                End If
            Next targetCell
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = True
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .Calculation = oldCalc
            End With
        End If
    End If
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        If oldCalc <> 0 Then .Calculation = oldCalc
    End With
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Name & ".Worksheet_Change()"
End Sub

Private Function HasValidationFormula(cell As Range) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ValidationNotExistsError
    If cell.Validation.Formula1 <> "" Then
        HasValidationFormula = True
    Else
        HasValidationFormula = False
    End If
    Exit Function
ValidationNotExistsError:
    HasValidationFormula = False
End Function
```

Any help would be great. This is the piece of code I am having trouble with even when adding the select case.

```
Select Case Target.Cells.Validation.Formula1                    
    Case "=SubList"
        If targetCell.Value = "" Then
            targetCell.Value = Choose
        ElseIf targetCell.Offset(, -1).Value = Choose Then
            targetCell.Value = ""
        ElseIf targetCell.Value = Choose Then
            'Do nothing
        Else
            Set nextCell = targetCell.Offset(, 1)
            If HasValidationFormula(nextCell) Then
                If nextCell.Validation.Formula1 = "=SubList" Then nextCell.Value = Choose
            End If
        End If
End Select
```

Comment: Please mark on which line you are getting the error and please post the exact error

Comment: Please check out the [help page on markdown formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), you can make code blocks by indenting by four spaces. It will make it much easier for people to understand the code you are posting.

Comment: i have made an edit to try and highlight the section i am having a problem with, even when adding in the select case line i am still getting errors about that chunk

Comment: Now getting End If without block If error

Comment: Try my answer, this line is extra.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of the Select statement is:

```
Select Case (expression)
    Case <case element>
    Case ...
    ....
    Case Else
End Select
```

In your case there is no `Select Case (expression)` before your first `Case "=SubList"`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem of your code, let see below:

```
'~~~~~~~~~~~~ above code ~~~~~~~~
                    If HasValidationFormula(nextCell) Then
                If nextCell.Validation.Formula1 = "=SubList" Then nextCell.Value = CHOOSE
            End If
        End If
    End Select
End If '<- this line is extra
'~~~~~~~~~~~~ below code ~~~~~~~~
```

Just remove the extra `End If`, It will OK.